Keyboard not working with linux no matter what i do
I have two computers one is a laptop Dell lattitude 3380 and one is a Desktop (Mobo: asus a520m-k), and i have two keyboard one who is straight out usb A who works flawlessly on linux windows and bios and on both computers which is perfect.
Now here comes the problem, the type C to usb A keyboard. On desktop computer it works on windows and bios but not on linux no matter what i do.
As for troubleshooting here is what i did :

I tried changing values [ on / off /auto ] in the bios to all these settings [ Legacy USB Support / XHCI Hand-off / Fast Boot ] no result.

I tried all the usb port that i have, nothing.

I tried using a powered usb hub a again nothing .

I looked at forum i found nothing or maybe i miss understood smtg.


on the software side :

I tried sudo apt update && apt upgrade no result

I changed os from ubuntu to mint again nothing,


regarding Logs i tried this command :
the result of dmesg | tail -n 10 is :
usb 1-6 : cant read configurations error -71
usb 1-6 : attempt power cycle
usb 1-6 : new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-6 : unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71

But when i try the keyboard on my laptop (Mint) it works perfectly
i am very confused on where is the problem and how to solve it. the only thing might be a problem is a setting in the bios that i am not aware of, or maybe a kernel thing.
thanks for reading / responding to my issue
...
